# Lodash _.pick() return empty objects

Tags: node.js, object, lodash

I'm using nodejs with mongodb. my `object` is something like i get from collection query. Then I filter it with `lodash` https://lodash.com/docs#pick.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var object = [{
    branchID: '1239',
    branchName: 'Branch Name 1',
    zoneID: '51',
    zoneName: 'Zone Name 1',
    regionID: '5',
    regionName: 'Region 1'
},
{
    branchID: '1240',
    branchName: 'Branch Name 2',
    zoneID: '52',
    zoneName: 'Zone Name 2',
    regionID: '5',
    regionName: 'Region 3'
}];

var test1 = _.pick(object, function (data) {
    return data.branchName == 1239
});

var test1 = _.pick(object, function (data) {
    return data.branchName == "1239"
});

console.log(test); // {}
```

I'm work with mongodb all of today.
This code above work as well until today's evening.
Normally, it should return me this :

```
{
    branchID: '1239',
    branchName: 'Branch Name 1',
    zoneID: '51',
    zoneName: 'Zone Name 1',
    regionID: '5',
    regionName: 'Region 1'
}
```

Do I do some mistake ? and do I have another way to filter this object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `_.pickBy` because this is a function you could also not have used a function but with using a function you need pickBy.

For further explanation: _.pick is when you want to pick exact keys from within an object like `_.pick({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, ['a', 'c'])` will return => `{a: 1, c: 3}` only which coincides with _.omit to do the same with omit: _.omit({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, ['b'])....

Then there comes the times when you want to check if a key or value match a certain criteria so you must use _.pickBy or _.omitBy:

```
_.pickBy({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, function(item){
    if(_.gte(item, 2)){
        return item;
    }
});
```

Will return {b: 2, c: 3} because those are greater than or equal to 2. In response to the comment to be sure you will probably want to do something like this if you have an array:

```
function checkIfMeetsMyCriteria(obj){
     _.pickBy(obj, function (data) {
         return data.branchName == "1239"
     });
}

_.map(objects, checkIfMeetsMyCriteria);
```

Comment: it's work now thanks you so much. I still wonder why `_.pick` is work before.
I have take a look on my version control many times. I see that I use `_.pick`. but for now I changed all my code to using `_.pickBy`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that neither `_.pick` nor `_.pickBy` can solve the OP's problem. Since both functions accepts an Object and not an Array. `object` in the OP's question is defined as an array of Objects.

Comment: True I assumed that since they had working code at one point they already were doing something like `_.each(objects, function(object){`

Comment: Assumptions should not be the basis of an answer. The only truth that should be considered is the question.

Comment: Ok I added stuff for your benefit also if thats the case then `object` is a terrible name for an array of objects in general `object` is a bad name no matter what, but `object` for a group of objects is outrageous

Comment: @Zargold Thanks for your explaination. I have more understand about `object` is one of my mistake. thanks you again I changed it now.

Comment: @Zargold It shouldn't be for my benefit only but for those who would have the chance to see this thread.

Comment: @Thesaria can you update the question, to conform with this answer?

Comment: @ryeballar what question is it really should be ? I'm not good much with English.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pick items that have branchID = 1239, but you were using branchName. That's why there is no data returns.

I think below code should work.

```
var test1 = _.pick(object, function (data) {
    return data.branchID == "1239"
});
```